# Spring Security + Keycloak: Accept Bearer Token

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

Somehow I'm lost with Spring Security and Keycloak.

In an application I **successfully** receive an **access token** from my Keycloak instance. I then use this token for a request against my Spring Security server (which uses the same Keycloak instance).

But all I get are **403** errors.

Here are code excerpts (written in kotlin):

**Security Config:**

```java
@KeycloakConfiguration
abstract class MyConfig : KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

   @Autowired
   lateinit var keycloakClientRequestFactory: KeycloakClientRequestFactory

   @Bean
   @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
   fun keycloakRestTemplate(): KeycloakRestTemplate {
      return KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory)
   }

   @Autowired
   @Throws(Exception::class)
   fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
      val keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider()
      keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(SimpleAuthorityMapper())
      auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider)
   }

   @Bean
   fun KeycloakConfigResolver(): KeycloakConfigResolver {
      return KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver()
   }

   @Throws(Exception::class)
   override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
      http.csrf().disable()
        .cors().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
      http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
   }

   @Bean
   override fun sessionAuthenticationStrategy(): SessionAuthenticationStrategy =
      RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(SessionRegistryImpl())

   @Bean
   fun keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
      filter: KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter): FilterRegistrationBean {
      val registrationBean = FilterRegistrationBean(filter)
      registrationBean.isEnabled = false
      return registrationBean
   }

   @Bean
   fun keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(
      filter: KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter): FilterRegistrationBean {
      val registrationBean = FilterRegistrationBean(filter)
      registrationBean.isEnabled = false
      return registrationBean
   }

   @Bean
   fun corsConfigurationSource(): CorsConfigurationSource {
      val configuration = CorsConfiguration()
      configuration.allowedOrigins = arrayListOf("*").toMutableList()
      configuration.allowedMethods = arrayListOf("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH","OPTIONS")
      configuration.allowCredentials = true
      configuration.allowedHeaders = arrayListOf("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type")
      val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
      source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration)
      return source
   }
}
```

**In my controller:**

```java
   @RequestMapping("/test")
   @ResponseBody
   fun test(): String {
      return "success"
   }
```

In my call to the server I can verify that the authorization header is set as follows: **Authorization: Bearer [Token]**

What am I missing? I'm glad for any help!

**Edit:**

**Spring Security Debug Log:**

```
2018-02-13 15:37:37.594 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /maintenance/secure-test; Attributes: [authenticated]
2018-02-13 15:37:37.594 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055286a: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@59b2: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.1.4; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2018-02-13 15:37:37.595 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2018-02-13 15:37:37.595 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2018-02-13 15:37:37.595 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@6b79755c, returned: -1
2018-02-13 15:37:37.596 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
        at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
[...skipping full stack trace...]

2018-02-13 15:37:37.596 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico']]
2018-02-13 15:37:37.596 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/maintenance/secure-test'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2018-02-13 15:37:37.596 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = true
2018-02-13 15:37:37.596 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using NegatedRequestMatcher [requestMatcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@40c8c1fa, matchingMediaTypes=[application/json], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
2018-02-13 15:37:37.596 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : httpRequestMediaTypes=[application/json, text/plain, */*]
2018-02-13 15:37:37.596 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : Processing application/json
2018-02-13 15:37:37.596 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher      : application/json .isCompatibleWith application/json = true
2018-02-13 15:37:37.596 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher  : matches = false
2018-02-13 15:37:37.596 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Did not match
2018-02-13 15:37:37.596 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Request not saved as configured RequestMatcher did not match
2018-02-13 15:37:37.596 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2018-02-13 15:37:37.596 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2018-02-13 15:37:37.596 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2018-02-13 15:37:37.597 DEBUG 13245 --- [io-10010-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

**Keycloak debug (on Spring server):**

```
2018-02-13 17:29:46.455 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-8] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest [URI]/maintenance/secure-test
2018-02-13 17:29:46.455 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-8] .k.a.t.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke /maintenance/secure-test
2018-02-13 17:29:46.455 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-8] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke [URI]/maintenance/secure-test
2018-02-13 17:29:46.455 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-8] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2018-02-13 17:29:46.461 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest [URI]/maintenance/secure-test
2018-02-13 17:29:46.462 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] .k.a.t.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke /maintenance/secure-test
2018-02-13 17:29:46.462 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke [URI]/maintenance/secure-test
2018-02-13 17:29:46.462 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
2018-02-13 17:29:46.463 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest [URI]/maintenance/secure-test
2018-02-13 17:29:46.463 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Request is to process authentication
2018-02-13 17:29:46.463 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Attempting Keycloak authentication
2018-02-13 17:29:46.467 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Verifying access_token
2018-02-13 17:29:46.572 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] o.k.a.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator       : Realm public keys successfully retrieved for client service-api. New kids: [omitted KID]
2018-02-13 17:29:46.573 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : successful authorized
2018-02-13 17:29:46.577 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] a.s.a.SpringSecurityRequestAuthenticator : Completing bearer authentication. Bearer roles: []
2018-02-13 17:29:46.578 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : User ’test' invoking ‚[URI]/maintenance/secure-test' on client 'service-api'
2018-02-13 17:29:46.578 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : Bearer AUTHENTICATED
2018-02-13 17:29:46.578 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Auth outcome: AUTHENTICATED
2018-02-13 17:29:46.586 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] o.k.a.s.management.HttpSessionManager    : Session created: [omitted sessione ID]
2018-02-13 17:29:46.588 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication success using bearer token/basic authentication. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@bb340ce7: Principal: test; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@68bb9634; Not granted any authorities
2018-02-13 17:29:46.588 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke [URI]/maintenance/secure-test
2018-02-13 17:29:46.588 DEBUG 14194 --- [io-10010-exec-9] o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler        : Policy enforcement is disabled.
```

Comment: Do you get any error from the adapter on in the KC server?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The keycloak server does not throw any exception. Did you mean the Spring Security server? I added the debug log from Spring Security and will look into enabling debug mode for the KC server as well.

Comment: Ok, it gets even more weird: the keycloak debug messages on the Spring server state that the user is successfully authorized by the token. But he does not seem to have any role or authority assigned to him.

Comment: I found the error. I missed in my configure method of the SecurityConfig the call to the super class (i.e. super.configure(http)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of completion I answer this question:

Like stated in a comment on the question, the problem was the call to **`super.configure(http)`** in `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

So, if you encounter a similar error check if you make this call. The config should look something like this:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
class MyConfig : KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
   // [...]
   @Throws(Exception::class)
   override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
      super.configure(http) // this call was missing
      // [...]
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you got any idea on how to verify the token. I am also trying to acheive the same to verify the token w/o any Role check.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you here. I'm no longer on this project. Good look!

Comment: I was able to make it work by following the Spring Security Documentation. Let me know if anyone need my github repo with the code.

Comment: Hey @TarunPande can you share the repo? I need reference for the same. Actually my KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter works with Bearer token but doesn't work with cookies.